# Find the general solution of the system

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Given:

\begin{cases} x- z = 1 \\ y + 2z - w = 3 \\ x + 2y + 3z - w = 7 \end{cases}

My work:
Use Gauss method
Leading variables: x,y, and z
Free variables: w
Express the leading variables x,y,and z in terms the free variable w.

1) I perform $-2R_2+R_3$ and got $x-z+w=1$ which replaces the third row of the system.

2) Then I perform $-R_1+R_3$ and got $w = 0$ which replaces the third row of the system.

3) Finally I perform $R_2+R_3$ and got $y+2z=3$ which replaces the third row of the system.

The system at the end looks like this:

\begin{cases} x- z = 1 \\ y + 2z - w = 3 \\ y = 3 -2 z \end{cases}

I am stuck as to how to get the leading variables in terms of the free variables since I know the value of the free variable now. But plugging in the value of w to the equations causes the free variable to disappear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you wrote the system as: $x, y, z, w$, so I followed suit.

The RREF gives:

- $w = 0$
- $y = 3 -2z$
- $x = 1 + z$

$z$ is a free variable.

Comment: Oh I see w = 0 plugging makes z a free variable. So I am suppose to write it now in terms of z.

Comment: That is correct. Thank you for showing your work and great job! Recall to upvote and/accept answers that are helpful! Regards

Comment: You were busy again today! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks, just saw some things I could not resist. Review queue is under 100, cannot wait!

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, you have a linear system of three equations in **four** unknowns. So at least one of the variables $x, y, w, z$ will be a *free variable* and in this case, since it turns out that $w$ is identically zero, its value is fixed, and so it cannot be a free variable.

What we end with, if you use an augmented coefficient matrix to row reduce, and with columns representing the coefficients of each variable, ordered as follows:
$x\;y\;w \; z$, , is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 &\mid& 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 2  &\mid& 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &\mid& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\mid& 0\end{pmatrix}$$

corresponding to the system of equations: $$\begin{align} x & = 1 + z \\ \\ y & = 3 - 2z \\ \\ w & = 0 \\ \\ z &= t\end{align}$$
where $z = t$ simply means that we have $z$ as the free variable, and we denote its value by the parameter $t$.

Then, the general solution is given by $$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ w \\ z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + t\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

For a particular solution, just let the parameter $z = t = 0$.

Comment: I think the coefficient matrix for the first row should be 1 0 -1 0 | 1 right?

Comment: No, the fourth column I've designated as representing the coefficient of $z$. See the column vector: ordered x, y, w, z (just so we can put the zero row at the bottom in the augmented matrix).

Comment: But z is free not w. Even with your ordered x,y,w,z. Should it not be that the third row of the coefficient matrix be 0 0 0 0 and the fourth row should be 0 0 0 1?

Comment: The $1$ in the third row represents $1 \cdot w = 0$. The whole row of zeros at the bottom mean that z can be anything, since $0\cdot z = 0 \implies $ z can be any value whatsoever.

Comment: The first row of the matrix means $1\cdot x - 1\cdot z = 1\iff x = 1 + z$. The second row of the matrix means $1\cdot y + 2z = 3\iff y = 3 - 2z$.

Comment: Oh I get it. Apologies I saw it wrong...

Comment: Not a problem! Glad to clarify.

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another UV +1

Answer (score 2):

Note that $w$ is necessarily zero, since $(***) - 2(**) - (*) = w = 7 - 2\cdot 3 - 1 = 0$, where $(*)$ denotes the first equation, $(**)$ denotes the second and $(***)$ the third. Then look at the matrix over which you have to compute the inverse. It has rank $2$. Why? Do you see a problem? Hence, you can't simplify it beyond the parametric form you have it in with $x-z=1$ and $y=3-2z$.